# excel stock and sales data management

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I need some help for my excel sales data management table.

I would like to get data from input to master table.

**input data columns:**

```
id; purchase no; date; ammount; total value
```

input data example:

```
100; 1-PJ1-11; 01.06.2016.; 10; 70,00
100; 2-PJ1-11; 03.06.2016.; 5; 35,00
```

I need this data to be in master sheet in columns next to the same product id for each work day. Or possibly for a selected date...

**master sheet** looks like this:

```
id; purchase price; sales price; margin; and here I need to have the data for each work day based on input data. So if I had new purchase it will be shown here for a certain date.
```

I know there are many possible options, but would like you to point me to the right directions.

Currently I do it manually with the sheet where I insert the input data per each workday and vlookup it back to the master sheet also for every workday which is really not the best possible option.

input data currently looks like this [image: input data currently]

I would like it to look like this 
[image: input data new]

master sheet looks like this 
[image: master sheet currently - some hidden columns between PROIZVOĐAČ and ULAZ]

I would like to pull the data from new input table to master sheet for each work date.

Comment: "I need some help" is a statement, not a question. Do you have a question (preferably a focused one, otherwise this is likely to be closed as too-broad, as you seem to realize with your disclaimer that "I know there are many possible options")?

Comment: The question is where to start from to achieve what I wrote? Can it be done with pivot, or I need some vba scripts or what can you suggest? Since I use vlookup currently and can't separate the inputs by multiple parameters. I use ID to connect the data right from the id and return them in appropriate cells in master sheet. It can surely be done easier than I do?